# Are there any other iOS apps other than Mail which can send email?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, gmail, email, smtp

I have been trying to find an iOS app which will let me send email from various accounts *without* going through Mail.app.

I know about [the comma trick](http://modernerd.com/post/535350679/solved-gmail-ipad-iphone-and-multiple-from) but that is *not* what I am after.

I also do not want to setup multiple accounts in Mail.app (which is going to give me multiple Inboxes, even if they are empty).

The closest solution I have found is [Ginbox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ginbox-gmail-google-apps-simplified/id369442234?mt=8) but unfortunately it seems to be broken under recent versions of iOS, and even if it worked, it's not a great solution, since it requires loading each Gmail account separately when you want to send an email from a different account.)

(If it doesn't exist… free iOS app idea!)

Comment: Keep your eyes out for Sparrow for iOS; it's been reported that it will be able to intelligently handle multiple accounts. I think it's currently being beta tested.

Comment: Thanks. Wil do. The ability to send without receiving will be key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iOS version of Sparrow has just been released, and it contains this functionality. In the settings for email accounts you can set up aliases. You can also set up a custom signature and SMTP server for each alias:

[image]
[image]

When composing a message, by default it will be sent from your default alias. If you want to change this, tap the "From" in the top center and you will be able to select which alias you want this message to come from:

[image]
[image]

Sparrow is available in the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sparrow/id492573565?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

There's a Gmail iOS app made by Google.

You can also use web mail accounts from Safari (I do this for temporary email accounts that I don't want to always be fetching email from.)

Comment: True, but there's no password saving and it's very slow to switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

Within a few weeks, you'll be able to download the brand new [Sparrow](http://blog.sparrowmailapp.com/) iOS app. The Mac OSX version works like a charm and I'm sure the iOS version will do to!

Answer (score 0):

Sparrow is available now and is quite good for a 1.0 product. No support for POP if you have to use that.
But it does much better than iOS mail.

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted this or why, but it *was* helpful. $3 at the App Store: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sparrow/id492573565?mt=8

Comment: @TJLuoma It was a good app for the year it lasted...